# Processing, Actionscript, javascript experience trying to learn java

Tags: java, processing

Hey so I've recently wanted to learn Java. Mainly because I've been using Processing so much lately and a lot of things I've done have been importing Java libraries. What I wanna know is that is there any place where I could find tutorials that would teach the language and its objects? I have experience with processing so I'm fairly good with the programming logic and can pretty much recognize java and get the general jist of the data flow of the application I'm just not familiar with very many of the objects in the language. Are there any exercises or places on the interwebs that would expand my "vocabulary" if you will of the language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sun (now Oracle) [Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) are a great way to start, and they're free!  Seriously, though, if you take the time to read all of this material and download, play with, and understand the code examples you will get a long way towards becoming a capable Java programmer.